# Geometric Series - Application word problem

Tags: word-problem

Payments of $1000 are deposited into a fund every six months and the account earns 10% interest, compounded semi-annually. How much is in the fund immediately after the 20th payment is made?

I'm aware on how to solve this, just really unsure of my common ratio that I computed, which is 2.1. Am I on the right track? Thank you!

Comment: The common ratio should be $1.1$ since the $10$% interest is compounded semi-annually that is every six months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the $k$th payment is made after $(k-1)\cdot 6$ months with respect to the first payment. Hence the first deposit of $1000$ dollars at the $20$th payment is increased to
$1000\cdot 1.1^{19}$. The second deposit of $1000$ dollars at the $20$th payment is increased to $1000\cdot 1.1^{18}$. Recall that if $r\not=1$ then
$$r^0+r^1+r^2+\dots +r^{n-1}=\frac{r^n-1}{r-1}.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: BUMP. I made a mistake in my solutions and one of my classmates explained it to me. Apparently, the first payment of 1,000 must not be counted as the first payment, the second one should be (the second payment being (1.1)1000+ 1000. May you explain this? Thank you.

Comment: What is your result and what is the result of your classmate?